# Python - Parsing JSON Data

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python, so forgive me if this is a beginner mistake. I'm trying to parse certain data from a JSON output.

Here is an example of the output:

```
    "data": [
    {
        "trackedEmails": [
            {
                "attachments": true,
                "fromEnv": {
                    "emailAddress": "user@test.com"
                },
                "fromHdr": {
                    "displayableName": "Joe Johnson",
                    "emailAddress": "user@test.com"
                },
                "id": "eNpFj11PwjAUhv9Lb2VJ243puGNGREIGgh",
                "info": "Indexed and archived",
                "received": "2020-10-23T16:19:00+0000",
                "route": "outbound",
                "senderIP": "10.10.10.10",
                "sent": "2020-10-23T16:19:00+0000",
                "status": "archived",
                "subject": "FW: Sent to Alias",
                "to": [
                    {
                        "displayableName": "",
                        "emailAddress": "external@test.com"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Here is how I'm trying to parse the data. This isn't the full script as some of the info is sensitive.

```
payload = {
    'data': [
        {
            'start': '2020-10-23T00:00:00+0000',
            'end': '2020-11-10T00:00:00+0000',
            'advancedTrackAndTraceOptions': {
                'from': '@example.com',
            }
        }
    ]
}


r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=str(payload))
data_r = r.json()


tracked_emails = []
for x in data_r:
  tracked_emails.append([x['info'], x['senderIP']])
```

Each time I try this I get "TypeError: string indices must be integers". I would just like to pull out certain info and export it to a CSV. (That part I have figured out). I've tried json.dumps and json.loads without any success. I've also tried adding an integer like: [x['info'][0], x['senderIP']].

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The error is telling you that you are trying to access an index of a string but you are using a string as the index instead of a number. Make sure that x is a dictionary type and not a string. You may need to use `json.loads()` on the data to convert it.

Comment: Iterating over a dict gives you its keys, hence `x` being a string. You probably want `data_r = r.json()['data']`.